# how to create a dynamic id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have:

```
<% @count=0%>
<%addr.each do |addr|%>
  <% @count+=1%>
  <%if addr==''%>
    <%= @count%>

    <%= form_for(:hotelUser,:url=>{:controller=>'HotelUsers',:action=>'createAddress'}) do |hotelUser|%>
      <%= hotelUser.text_area(:address,:cols=>67,:rows=>3)%>
      <p style="text-align: center;width: 50%;">
        <a href="#" id="example-hide" class="btn-orange3" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">BACK</a><%= submit_tag("PROCEED TO PAYMENT",{:action=>'show'})%>
      </p>
    <%end%>
    <% break%>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

I want to concatenate the value of **@count** with `text_area` `id :address`. For example if **@count=4** then i will get **:address4**. Please help me solve this problem?

Comment: format the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way

```
<%= hotelUser.text_area(:address, :cols => 67, :rows => 3, :id => "address"+@count.to_s)%>
```

Done!

Comment: I am getting `undefined method `address' for #<HotelUser:0x6b6c118>`.In my table i have address1,address2.....

Comment: you don't have address field in HotelUser model?

Comment: i am getting id dynamic, can i get name also

Comment: You can surely get name dynamic, but it will throw error if column of that name is missing in the database

Comment: sir, this is what i am getting in the source code of the browser `<textarea cols="67" id="address#{@count.to_s}" name="hotelUser[address#{@count.to_s}]" rows="3">
</textarea>`............but the concatenate is not working.

Comment: I got my answer by using `<textarea cols="67" id="address<%= @count.to_s%>" name="hotelUser[address<%= @count.to_s%>]" rows="3">
</textarea>`.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<%= hotelUser.text_area(:address,:cols=>67,:rows=>3, :id => 'address<%=@count%>')%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table has fields `address1, address2, ...` you need to **reference that field** in the **first parameter of the text_area helper**. So the code would be:

```
<%= hotelUser.text_area("address#{@count}",:cols=>67,:rows=>3)%>
```